# A certain data points with different plot marker and color

Tags: plotting

I have a data set, say `list={{1,2,0.1},{2,4,0.02},{3,10,0.3},{4,20,0.6},{20,100,0.9}}`, I want to use one plot marker eg: black unfilled square for say `{{1,2,0.1},{3,10,0.3},{4,20,0.6}}` and another say circles with blue colors for `{20,100,0.9}` and `{2,4,0.02}` point.I also need `Joined->True` in **ErrorListLogPlot** or even just the **ListLogPlot** .I also need to generalize these for any plot markers of different sizes and shapes.

P.S the third column represents the errorbar.

Comment: `list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 10}}; ListPlot[List /@ list, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon, could you please check the updated question again?

Comment: `Show[ListPlot[List@Last@list], 
 ListPlot[Most@list, PlotStyle -> {Black}]]`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci. But this I can not generalize. What if I want one middle point is also of the same color, or Could please check the updated question?

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 10}, {4, 20}, {20, 100}}
xss = {list[[{1, 3, 4}]], list[[{2, 5}]]} 

polygon[position_, n_, r_] := 
 Polygon[position + r # & /@ CirclePoints[n]]
circle[position_, r_] := Circle[position, r Sqrt[2]/2]
disk[position_, r_] := Disk[position, r Sqrt[2]/2]

r = 2;
markers = {{Blue, EdgeForm[Black], polygon[#, 4, r]} & /@ 
    First@ xss , {Green, EdgeForm[Black], disk[#, r]} & /@ Last@xss};

markerSize = {10, 10};
plotMarkers = {{Transparent, EdgeForm[Black], 
     polygon[{0, 0}, 4, r]} , {Green, EdgeForm[Black], 
     disk[{0, 0}, r]}} // Map[Graphics[#, ImageSize -> markerSize] & ];

plotRange = 
  Transpose@list // Map[{Min@#, Max@#} &] // 
   Map[{#[[1]] - 5, #[[2]] + 5} &];
ListPlot[
 xss,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> plotMarkers ,
 (*Epilog\[Rule] markers,
 AspectRatio\[Rule]Automatic,*)
 PlotRange -> plotRange,
 PlotLegends -> {"A", "B"}]
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57777/discussion-on-answer-by-unchartedworks-a-certain-data-points-with-different-plot).